# I get this error on my console on Google Chrome when I am trying to make sure that my javascript code is working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, console

[Error that I get!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj3Wf.png)

How can I fix this error on my browser to make my code working?

Answer (score 0):

I think the .sw.js is a Service Worker that your script tries to load and fails.

Info about serviceworkers is in the Chrome Browser -> chrome://serviceworker-internals/